# Clear values from FORM with BUTTON

Tags: forms, input

I would like to have a button on my form that could clean all the values. I have found some Javascript codes but they reset the value to the "Default Value".

```
<form id="prova" action="#" method="post">DATE:          
<input id="datepicker" name="date1" type="text"  />
Period from: <input  id="datepicker2" name="date2" type="text" value=" <?php echo $name3 ?>"/>  
to <input  id="datepicker3" name="date3" type="text" value= "<?php echo $name4  ?>" />
```

Comment: Please show more code and if you want to like emptied to every input box then you should try `$('input').val('');`

Comment: Well. How should I insert this on my code?

Comment: You should write an event which triggers on your reset button and after that you emptied your input box by writing this code inside of that event. Hope you got my point.

Comment: Thank you so much, this works!

Comment: My pleasure. @talendguy

Answer (score 0):

The reset() method resets the values of all elements in a form (same as clicking the Reset button).

```
<form id="myForm">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br><br>
  <input type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('myForm').reset();" value="Reset form">
</form>
```

Working code sample in the plunkr link http://plnkr.co/edit/ZJnGbNB7m9XKDwyL4Zte?p=preview